# How to pass variable from one Javascript to another Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I tried the following, trying to pass a variable from one JavaScript file to another JavaScript variable. My first JavaScript file:

```
var x = "sachin";
```

My other JavaScript file can't access that `x` variable value. How do I solve this? I can access that `x` variable and same value in another file.

Comment: I know its vague, but try `window.x = "sachin"`.

Comment: use with global variable and order the js file one by one `var x = "sachin"` is first js file .Then add next js file in below of the file .order is important .`<script src="var x=sachin"></script> <script src="2nd file"></script>`

Comment: make sure the file with the variable is before the other file

Comment: *"I **can** access that x variable and same value in another file."* - Are you saying that `x` in file 1 can't be accessed from file 2 but can be from file 3? In which order do you include the files?

Comment: You mean two scripts on the same page or different pages?

Comment: This would be a good time to take a few minutes to read through [ask]. Question is too vague without proper details and relevant code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

see about local and global variables for more info.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp.

Make sure your var X is not inside a function and that your file is load in the correct order.

```
<script src="file1.js"><script> //declare var x=1 here
<script src="file2.js"><script> // you can access x from here.
```

Comment: Basically my project is a simple chat app,which has credentials like API_KEY,like that,does this method works here?

Answer (score 11):

A variable in global scope can be access from all javascript file.
 Your first js file

```
  //first.js file
    var globalVariable={
       x: 'sachin'
    };
```

And your second js file

```
    //second.js file
    alert(globalVariable.x);
```

And in html page add-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you do it without two `script` elements? Basically import `second.js` inside `first.js`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're running JavaScript in the browser. The order in which you include these files matters. If your script tags are in the wrong order, like...

```
<script src="file2.js"></script>
<script src="file1.js"></script>
```

If `x`is defined in file1, you can't use it in file2. file2 loads and runs first.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the simplest ways would be to make the variable global or add it to a particular namespace that both files share.

To make it global (not ideal):

```
window.x = "sachin";
```

To add to a common namespace (keep in mind this namespace is global too):

- Create a namespace in a third file, `MYAPP = {};`
- Use namespace in second file: `MYAPP.x = "sachin;"`
- Access variable from same namespace in third file: `MYAPP.x`