# Access js variable of one file in another file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 js files: 1.js and 2.js.
In 1.js I have a variable

```
var test ='Hello';
```

I'm trying to access the variable in 2.js

```
alert(test);
```

Sample Code:
1.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = 'Hello';
});
```

2.js :

```
 $(function () {
       function getData(){
            alert(test);
       }
   });
```

In my aspx page order of js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/1.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/2.js?"></script>
```

I know the question is asked before many times but none of the answers seems to work for me.

Comment: JS doesn’t work like that. `test` is scoped to the function it’s defined in, here the anonymous function passed in to jQuery’s DOMReady shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `var test` is not inside a function and that your file is load in the correct order.
In your first file use something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var test = "myVar"
</script>
// Now here include your js file too JS file 
// Or set in window scope like window.test="myVar";
```

And in your `JS file` use like

```
$(function() {
  alert(test);
  // alert(window.test);
});
```

A variable in global scope can be access from all javascript file.
Your first js file

**Here is another way.**

```
//first.js file don't put variable inside any function here.
var globalVariable={
   test: 'myVar'
};
```

And your second js file

```
//second.js file
alert(globalVariable.test);
```

And in html page add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

[More from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255861/how-to-pass-variable-from-one-javascript-to-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store the variable value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem('test ', 'Hello');
});
```

In the next file retrieve it using

```
$(function () {
       function getData(){
         var data = sessionStorage.getItem('test');
            alert(data );
       }
   });
```

Note the file 1.js need to be loaded before 2.js

Comment: Important to note storage only stores strings....booleans and numbers need to be type cast on retrieval and arrays/objects need to be stringified and parsed