# How to use variable from one .js file in another .js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a website with html and jquery. I have data.js (with `const travelInfoURL = '<url>';`) file with the url I need. I want to use it in main.js file, but I am getting the following error:

> main.js:130 Uncaught ReferenceError: travelInfoURL is not defined

**How to solve this issue?** I tried to export the travelInfoURL in data.js (`export{travelInfoURL};`), but it didn't help. The files are located in the same directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variable from one Javascript to another Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255861/how-to-pass-variable-from-one-javascript-to-another-javascript-file)

Comment: There's an article on import/export [here](https://javascript.info/import-export)

Comment: I do not want to acces the url in the html page, but only between two js files.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing the JS runtime that is being used, but your question indicates you are at least using ES6 import/export syntax.

Your question does not indicate that you are importing what you are exporting. If you want to export `travelInfoURL` not as the default export of the file, you can do so by writing:

```
export const travelInfoURL  = '<url>';
```

In the other file you can import this as:

```
import { travelInfoURL } from './main';
```

Comment: When I use the above import statement, I am gettin this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Without knowing more about the environment you are working with, I can't answer why this may be the case.